# Indexing in mongodb query doesn't boost performance

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have aggregate function to get all of the data from the collection. The query works fine until I add a sort stage in that query. From the time I added the sort stage in that query, it takes so much time and caused timeout error in my code. What filed should I give index to make this query faster.

This is the sample document of onu_profile collection

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f056023324dc0369a9b9c60"
  },
  "serial": "UBNT29F59750\t",
  "profile_name": "",
  "hostname": "",
  "status": "inactive",
  "tcont": {},
  "gemport": {},
  "portvlan": {},
  "setting_details": [],
  "device_mac": null,
  "onu_authlist_gpon_port": null,
  "onu_authlist_profile_id": null,
  "created_on": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1594211211178"
    }
  },
  "updated_on": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1594211211178"
    }
  },
  "created_by": "ye.htun",
  "updated_by": "ye.htun"
}
```

This is the sample document of dbm_status collection

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63b4493585b12c2da3c7e50a"
  },
  "hostname": "122X01ZMTY-B03-P16-SCP004779",
  "device_type": "ONU",
  "last_seen": "2023-07-18T14:00:29.220006582+06:30",
  "status": 1,
  "gpon_name": "CA1-MYEX08ZMTY-B",
  "last_checked_on": "2023-07-18T14:00:29.210486574+06:30",
  "last_seen_on": "2023-07-18T14:00:29.220006582+06:30",
  "olt_hostname": "OVF-123X01ZMTY",
  "olt_ip": "172.28.22.224",
  "onu_profile_id": "75",
  "phase_state": "Working",
  "pon_port": "2",
  "serial": "SCSOACA0A488",
  "signal": "-22.520"
}
```

This is the mongo query

```
db.onu_profile.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or:[{'serial': {'$regex': '(?i)(.*)(.*)'}}, {'hostname': {'$regex': '(?i)(.*)(.*)'}}, {'device_mac': {'$regex': '(?i)(.*)(.*)'}}]
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
  from: "dbm_status",
  localField: "serial",
  foreignField: "serial",
  as: "dbm_status"
}
    },
    {
      $addFields:{
  dbm_status : { "$arrayElemAt" : ["$dbm_status", 0]}
},
{$sort:{created_on:-1}}
    }
])
```

I tried indexing the created_on field but that doens't work. I was expecting to get faster performance when i add the sort stage in that query

Comment: Where is the sort stage?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to add that stage in my query, Now I've update my query